# In OCaml, how do I re-assign a global variable inside a function

Tags: global-variables, ocaml

My program has the following global variable:

```
let a = (0.0,0.0);;
```

And the following, where `eval e1` returns a string_of_float and `somefunc e2` returns a tuple.

```
let rec output_expr = function
    Binop(e1, op, e2) -> 
            let onDist = float_of_string(eval e1) and onDir = somefunc e2 in 
            let newA = onDir in (
                   fprintf oc "\n\t%s" ("blah");
                   fprintf oc "\n\t%s" ("blah");
                   fprintf oc "\n\t%s" ("blah");
                   let a = newA
            )
```

Now, the code above gives me the following error:

```
Error: This expression has type bool
       but an expression was expected of type unit
Command exited with code 2.
```

I want `let a = newA` to change the value of the global variable `a`. How can I do that?

Comment: You don't. That's one of the most important characteristics of functional programming. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it you need to make the value a reference,

```
let a = ref (0.0, 0.0)
```

then later that state can change by,

```
a := (1.0, 2.0);
```

In a functional world you would not want to have this global state. Sometimes it is very helpful, but in this particular case that is doubtful. You should pass the value `a` into your function and return a new value (`a'`) that can be used subsequently; note that the value never changes, but new values take the place and are used in further computation.

In your particular case, I think you need to ask yourself why a function named `output_expr` modifies some global state, or returns anything but `unit`. But maybe this is a toy example for our consumption, so I will leave it at that.

Comment: I hope you choose a different route in future projects / assignments.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign to a variable (local or global is the same) in OCaml. There's simply no syntax in the language for it. In other words, variables in OCaml are what other languages call "constants" -- they get a value once in initialization, and that's it.

However, you can use a mutable data structure, which offers ways to modify its contents. Data structures are reference types, you can hold a reference to the data structure in a variable, and modify the contents, without needing to assign to the variable.

nlucaroni mentioned such a data structure, `ref`, which is a simple mutable cell holding a value of the desired type. There are other mutable data structures, like arrays, strings, and any record with `mutable` fields. Each has its own way of modifying the contents.

However, mutable state can mostly be avoided in functional programming, and if you are relying on mutable state, it may be an indication that you are not doing it the functional way.

Answer (score 2):

In OCaml, values are immutable. You can't change the content of a value and should reorganize your code so that you don't need to.
Here your function `output_expr` should return the `newA` and this value should be used instead of `a` after that.

Actually you can have mutable variables using references but you should only use them if you know what you do and think they are better suited for a particular use case, never because you don't understand immutability.